# c# webapi post() and post([FromBody])

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I'm building an webapi in c# to be called by an outside server.

let's say my API address is www.server.com/webapi/service1

when I set the address above in the app that will use it, it sends a simple POST with an *empty body* to service1 and waits for a specific KEY as response (in body), like an authentication. ok.

the same service1 can be called, using POST too, passing a raw JSON in the body, and I'm using the [FromBody] attribute to get the body and process.

I tried this to manage the empty POST call and the call with body data:

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("webapi/service1")]
        public HttpResponseMessage Post()
        {
            var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            resp.Content = new StringContent(TokenKey.ToString(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "text/html");
            return resp;
        }

[HttpPost]
        [Route("webapi/service1")]
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody] RetornoChat retornoChat)
        {
            await closedChat(retornoChat); //process body

            return resp;

        }
```

but it was not working.I manage a workaround like the code below, I check if the class in [FromBody] is empty, if this is the case return the special string to validate and finish, if there is a body then get the data validate and process. I'm wondering if there is a better solution.

I really thought that the solution was to double the post method and when there was a body it would call the post with the [frombody] and when there is no body it would go to the empty post.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("webapi/service1")]
            public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody] RetornoChat retornoChat)
            {

                var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                resp.Content = new StringContent(TokenKey.ToString(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "text/html");

                if (retornoChat == null)
                {

                }
                else 
                {
                    //get the body data and process
                }

                return resp;

            }
```

Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: Web API won't allow you to have two actions with the same route. You can have two overloaded methods in your controller, but they have to have different routes (if you're going to use the same verb). You should be able to just use the version that has the parameter and give it a default value of `null` (e.g. `[FromBody] RetornoChat retornoChat = null`).

Comment: If you don't want two routes, then this is a valid solution.  The only thing I would add is that you create the response based on the request and not just new it up.  Also, I wouldn't respond with text/html, but that's just me.

Comment: thanks @KennethK., I like it your idea and will give a null default value...

Comment: @Rogala i return plain text because it's a request from the other service... what do you mean by create the response based on the request?

Comment: Just keep in mind that the value will also result in `null` if the deserializer can't deserizliaze the payload. So if you're POSTing JSON, and you forget a curly brace somewhere, then even though you think you're submitting data, the deserialization will fail, and you'll receive `null` in the action parameter.

Comment: good point @KennethK. Can I set a try catch to deal with this deserialization fail?

Comment: The deserialization is handled by ASP.NET itself. There may be a way to hook into it, but I'm not aware of such a mechanism myself.

Comment: @user77 when responding you should do something like Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result) where result is an object.  Send me a chat request, and I can explain more there.

Comment: @user77 did you solve the issue? I am facing same kind of issue

Comment: hi @ghetal, I endup with the solution I posted in the question, check if retornoChat class is null inside the async Task.... 'kennethK ' also gave some good points...

Comment: I traced my issue and found that actually this was due to authorization I am using. When I solved that, the formbody issue got solved automatically.